# duplicity: how to search for file versions in all backup chains?

Tags: duplicity

duplicity can show file changes in the most recent backup chain with `collection-status --file-changed <relpath>`
But what if I realized that I lost a file and wanted to search for it in all (many) backup chains?
Is there any option better than manually listing chains one by one, painstakingly specifying individual backup dates?

Comment: The Same question has been already well ansered imho: [Duplicity: How to list versions of a file?](https://serverfault.com/questions/345056/duplicity-how-to-list-versions-of-a-file)